# How to create properties of classes within classes?

Tags: class, delphi, properties, tobjectlist

For Delphi XE6, I am creating a class called TAccountSearch.  It has a small number of properties, and a class of TObjectList.  My issue is I cannot seem to make the TObjectList class exposed as a property.

Code Snippet... Create the class I will use for TObjectList

```
  type
  TSearchHits = class
  ID: Integer;
  Name : String;
  ...
  end;
```

Now create the class which contains an instance of TObjectList...

```
type
  TAccountSearch = class
  private
    zSearchPhrase: string;
    zList: TObjectList<TSearchHits>;
    ...
    property SearchPhrase: string read zSearchPhrase; 
    property MyList:TObjectList<TSearchHits> read TObjectList<TSearchHits>;
end;
```

TAccountSearch.SearchPhrase is a valid property.  TAccountSearch.MyList is not....
From the accountSearch class, How do I give the calling program access to SearchHits as a Property?  Second, if I don't include a WRITE definition on the PROPERTY line, the property is considered read only.
Is that accurate?  Is that the proper way to make read only properties?

Comment: `property MyList: TObjectList<TSearchHits> read zList write zList;` (or `write SetzList` if you need a setter procedure).

Comment: That was it... submit as answer and I will credit it.  As to the second question, is that the proper way to create a read only property?

Comment: I covered them both in my answer.

Comment: @user1009073 I'm curious about something. Why do you want to expose TObjectList as a read only property? If you want to provide read only access to the TObjectList object (external code can't change referecne of your TObjectList to point to some other TObjectList then instead of using property you can simply expose your internal TObjectList by moving its declaration from private to public section. But if you are interested in only exposing contents of your TObjectList (items) to be read only to other code make indexed property which will forward the data from your TObjectList instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You access the instance variable `zList` in order to gain access to the internal storage:

```
property MyList: TObjectList<TSearchHits> read zList write zList;
```

Use `write SetMyList` if you need a setter procedure.

You can use a getter function as well to gain access:

```
private
  function GetMyList: TObjectList<TSearchHits>;
published
  property MyList: TObjectList<TSearchHits> read GetMyList write SetMyList;
```

where the getter function would be written something like

```
function TAccountSearch.GetMyList: TObjectList<TSearchHits>;
begin
  Result := zList;
end;
```

The way to implement read-only properties is simply to omit the `write` portion.

```
property MyList: TObjectList<TSearchHits> read zList;
```